# Where does atmoz/sftp store the files?

Tags: sftp

After setting up `atmoz/sftp` via Docker, where, in the container, am I supposed to find the uploaded files?

I have tried different `compose` files (see below) but:

1- Can't find the uploaded files.
2- With all the below configurations when I connect from a local client, I see the same directory.

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  sftp:
    container_name: sftp
    image: atmoz/sftp:alpine
    expose:
      - 22
    ports:
      - 22:22
    command:
      - user:pass:1001
    volumes:
      - /usr/sftp/data:/home/user/upload
      - /usr/sftp/keys/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub:/home/user/.ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub:ro
      - /usr/sftp/keys/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub:/home/user/.ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub:ro
```

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  sftp:
    container_name: sftp
    image: atmoz/sftp:alpine
    expose:
      - 22
    ports:
      - 22:22
    command:
      - user:pass:1001::/home/user/upload
    volumes:
      - /usr/sftp/data:/home/user/upload
      - /usr/sftp/keys/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub:/home/user/.ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub:ro
      - /usr/sftp/keys/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub:/home/user/.ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub:ro
```

I see this from the client (test.txt is the file I just copied).

[image]

And this is persisted with different containers (I run `up` and `down` several times, and `test.txt` is always there when I connect via the client).

This is what I get when accessing the container.

[image]

`/home/user/upoload` is empty.
[image]

Comment: As an variant you can explore path 
`/home/user/upload` 
as stated in loutput above.  Explain in more details if I understand it not clearly.

Comment: @TomNewton Thanks for the reply. `/home/user/upload` is empty (see above). There is no trace of `test.txt` or all the other dotfiles.

Comment: `when I connect via the client`  
And which path is there in settings or command in the client software? If there is switched on the logging in the client - it is worth to check it too

Comment: The 5th parameter is the shared directory found in the user home dir. And without it, is will be the root of the user home dir: `/home/user`